# Setting up lighttpd server

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, lighttpd

I'm attempting to setup a lighttpd server and when I try to install php-cgi I receive this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
php7.2-cgi : Depends: php7.2-common (= 7.2.3-1ubuntu1) but    
7.2.5-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: View a list of actual held packages with ```dpkg --get-selections | grep hold```.  This will tell you if it's an actual hold, or another problem.  Feel free to update your question with that info.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50242053/after-ubuntu-18-04-upgrade-php7-2-curl-cannot-be-installed) will help?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.